# Can we use each other in this sentence?

Tags: usage

In 1996, Mrs. Clara and Mr. Smith died. They buried **each other** in the Mexico.

I couldn't take a look at the usage of the verb ''to bury''. However, the point is to check out whether or not I can use ''each other''.

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  *Each other* means that the action was "reciprocal": Clara buried Smith and Smith buried Clara. That seems very unlikely, unless there was a very complicated suicide pact!

What you probably mean is *Both were buried in Mexico** or *Each was buried in Mexico**.

* <sup>**NOTE**: *Mexico* is a proper name, so it doesn't take an article.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can use the reciprocal pronoun 'each other' when two or more people do the same thing. Two dead people cannot bury each other, or do anything else. Did you mean they were buried together in Mexico?